# Using Java fork join framework on single processor

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I've started to use fj JAVA framework.
As I understand it just divides big task like algorithm computation and divides it into 
small threads.
The question is if it worth to use this framework on a single processor machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the oracle documentation [JAVA FORK/JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html):

> The fork/join framework is an implementation of the ExecutorService interface that helps you take advantage of multiple processors. It is designed for work that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively. The goal is to use all the available processing power to enhance the performance of your application.

So it's main goal is multiple processors architecture.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A single processor (a single single-core processor) can't utilize multiple threads as it can only run one thread at a time. In fact, the overhead of thread managing will slow your computation down a bit.

Related: You can get the number of processors available to your application during runtime. See [`Runtime.availableProcessors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29).

Comment: When your first thread goes to sleep for whatever reason, your second thread can already start executing.  There can be an advantage in multithreading on a single core CPU.

Comment: I don't think I'm following your thoughts. Yes, what you stated is true. Yet I can't make up an example where this would help in splitting a single task to multiple threads.

Comment: @Slanec This happens when one thread must wait for an IO-operration to complete; like waiting for data to be read from a disk.  Wether multithreading helps on a single-core depends on the task.  As an example where multithreading helps think about compiling a large number of source files.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use the number of processors at runtime to determine the configuration of your execution.

Even if you have a single core machine, you may have the ability to execute more than one thread at time, therefore you can leverage this using f.e. fork-join.
If you really have just a single execution thread on your cpu, you will have a small overhead from using a multithreading framework compared to plain execution.

On the other hand: If you write your application on a single core machine and have no profit from it, you may be able to use a different machine later, or give the application to users which have multicore/threading machines. Without building the application again or change anything you can make use of that capabilities then.

So it really depends on the way you expect to use your application now - and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is still useful on 1-core processors if there is significant amount of IO operations. Otherwise it can even hurt.

Comment: I understand the advantages of multithreading but question is if FJ which is used for dividing big task to small subtasks can help

Comment: Well, if task contains significant amount of IO operations, than my answer is relevant.

Comment: But is it worth to use FJ for this or it's better to create a separate thread which executes IO?

Answer (score 0):

Each processor has a thread scheduler which can allocate time to ***one single*** thread to do its work. So if you have 100 threads and just one processor, the scheduler will just switch between those 100 threads. However, with that being said, there is no advantage in using multiple threads on a single processor because effectively what it happens, as I described, is that the scheduler just switches between threads really fast. Plus, context switching is quite slow from a CPU perspective.

Comment: I _think_ this is what I wrote. Of course you can have multiple threads. But the processor will only run one at a time (and switch between them which is what causes the overhead I mentioned). Anyway, running a computation on multiple threads will never be faster than running it in a single thread, will it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you are most certainly right. I might have rushed reading through the lines there.